# Setting vm.max_map_count with tuned

Tags: openshift

Trying to set vm.max_map_count with the node tuning operator and the openshift ClusterLogging operator. Openshift version is 4.9.17, cluster logging and elasticsearch operators are latest.

This is my tuned configuration:

```
apiVersion: tuned.openshift.io/v1
kind: Tuned
  name: common-services-es
  namespace: openshift-cluster-node-tuning-operator
spec:
  profile:
    - data: |
        [main]
        summary=Optimize systems running ES on OpenShift nodes
        include=openshift-node
        [sysctl]
        vm.max_map_count=262144
      name: common-services-es
  recommend:
    - match:
        - label: component
          type: pod
          value: elasticsearch
      priority: 5
      profile: common-services-es
```

My ClusterLogging operator configuration is the default operator, and I can verify the labels `component=elasticsearch` on the pod.

Getting the pod logs with the following command

```
for p in `oc get pods -n openshift-cluster-node-tuning-operator -l openshift-app=tuned -o=jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.name} {end}'`; do printf "\n*** $p ***\n" ; oc logs pod/$p -n openshift-cluster-node-tuning-operator | grep applied; done
```

returns `tuned.daemon.daemon: static tuning from profile 'common-services-es' applied` on all 3 of my es nodes, but the elasticsearch pod still fails to start with the error  `max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [253832] is too low, increase to at least [262144]` and running `sysctl vm.max_map_count` on the nodes confirm the value is 253832.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that IBM Cloud openshift doesn't use machineconfigs, and tuned uses machineconfigs.